# Ограничение прав пользователя на редактирование записей в django

Tags: django

На сайте зарегистрированные пользователи могут создавать и редактировать комментарии к постам. Пользователь должен редактировать только свой комментарий. Как ограничить права пользователя, чтобы он не мог редактировать комментарии других пользователей?
В views использую CBV.

Answer (score 1):

Если для правки комментария используете UpdateView, то можно переопределить метод form_valid

```
def form_valid(self, form):
if form.instance.user != self.request.user:
  return HttpResponseForbidden()
return super().form_valid(form)
```